# How can I create YAML configuration for my Symfony web app? (not a bundle)

Tags: symfony

I'd like to manage custom configuration for my Symfony 5 web app, similar to bundle config in `config/packages/app.yaml`

The [documentation for bundle configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html) shows how to do this for a bundle, but I'm looking for a way to do this in a typical web app, and not a bundle.

Here's what I've done: (I don't think the code itself is relevant to the question because the files are not being loaded at all)

- created `src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`
- created `src/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php`

At this point when I try to load config in a controller by injecting `ContainerBagInterface $params` and calling `$params->get('app')`, I get the following error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app"

Am I missing a step to wire this up or is setting up config like this not possible outside of a bundle?

Comment: You can register your extension inside of src/Kernel.php https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html

Comment: Confirmed; Adding `$container->registerExtension(new AppExtension());` to `configureContainer()` inside of `src/Kernel.php` wired it up. Thanks!